# JSON is not loading from server

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON file which i want to load end it is working fine when I am trying to load that file locally from my hard drive.

```
    function save(){                                    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'cameras.json',
        dataType: "JSON",
        async : false,
        success: function(data) {

        var output = data.result["0"].Address;
        alert(output);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("Error")
        }
    }); 

}
```

When i want to get access to this JSON file from my server:

```
    function save(){                                    
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://192.168.0.21:8080/json.html?type=cameras',
        dataType: "JSON",
        async : false,
        success: function(data) {

        var output = data.result["0"].Address;
        alert(output);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert("Error")
        }
    }); 

}
```

It's not working and I am getting error script.

What can be issue with that ?

Comment: You're loading `html` file while your request expects `JSON`

Comment: You are using alert were its preferred to use console.log and instead of alert Error use console.log(data) and it get you the server response. Try with firebug and it gets you better information. And this data.result["0"].Address; Are you referring to 0 of an indexed array.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Unfortunately, I think that remote (i.e. away from *localhost*) ajax calls are forbidden - or something similar - for security reasons.

Depending on your purposes, you can resolve the problem with a 2-steps action:
You can call - via ajax - a local server class which loads the remote file via REST web service.
I solved this way...

Comment: Obviously for _localhost_ I suppose the same server of the application... not the machine on which the site is viewed.